File upload field not working magento 2.4
I've created a custom form in adminhtml, in form i have a file upload file, this form is used both when create a new row and when edit existing row, when i'm creating the upload field appears correctly, but not when i'm editing, i'm using ui component, not php block form
when i'm creating row

when i'm editing row

my form.xml
<argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
    <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="provider" xsi:type="string">statements_form.statements_record_grid_list_data_source</item>
        <item name="deps" xsi:type="string">statements_form.statements_record_grid_list_data_source</item>
    </item>
    <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Crear nuevo aviso</item>
    <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">data</item>
        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">statements_form</item>
    </item>
    <item name="template" xsi:type="string">templates/form/collapsible</item>
    <item name="buttons" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="save" xsi:type="string">Reevolution\Statements\Block\Adminhtml\Edit\Save</item>
    </item>
</argument>
<dataSource name="statements_record_grid_list_data_source">
    <argument name="dataProvider" xsi:type="configurableObject">
        <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">Reevolution\Statements\Model\DataProvider</argument>
        <argument name="name" xsi:type="string">statements_record_grid_list_data_source</argument>
        <argument name="primaryFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
        <argument name="requestFieldName" xsi:type="string">id</argument>
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="submit_url" xsi:type="url" path="*/*/save"/>
            </item>
        </argument>
    </argument>
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="js_config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/form/provider</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</dataSource>
<fieldset name="general_information">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Información general</item>
            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">20</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <field name="title" sortOrder="20" formElement="input">
        <settings>
            <dataType>text</dataType>
            <visible>true</visible>
            <label translate="true">Título</label>
        </settings>
    </field>
    <field name="description" sortOrder="10" formElement="textarea">
        <settings>
            <dataType>text</dataType>
            <visible>true</visible>
            <label translate="true">Descripción</label>
        </settings>
    </field>
    <field name="path_file" sortOrder="20" formElement="fileUploader">
        <settings>
            <label translate="true">Archivo</label>
        </settings>
        <formElements>
            <fileUploader>
                <settings>
                    <uploaderConfig>
                        <param xsi:type="string" name="url">statements/file/upload</param>
                    </uploaderConfig>
                </settings>
            </fileUploader>
        </formElements>
    </field>
</fieldset>


have you maybe found a solution? I have similar problem while creating product attribute that should use fileUploader ;)
